# How to use ggplot in a loop with computed parameters?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, zoo

I am trying to produce a variable number of rectangles (layers) in a ggplot of a zoo object. I would like to do this in a loop since I do not know ahead of time how many rectangles I will need. Here is a toy example.

```
library("zoo")
library("ggplot2")
set.seed(1)
y <- runif(50, min = 1, max = 2)
start <- as.numeric(as.Date("2018-01-01"))
x <- as.Date(start:(start + 49))
x.zoo <- zoo(y, order.by = x)
## Fill areas
bars <- data.frame(start = c(x[5], x[20], x[35]),
                end = c(x[10], x[25], x[40]))
```

I can plot these manually with this code:

```
## Plot manually
print(autoplot.zoo(x.zoo, facets = NULL) +
        geom_rect(aes(xmin = bars[1,1],
                  xmax = bars[1,2], ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
                  fill = "pink", alpha = 0.01) +
        geom_rect(aes(xmin = bars[2,1],
                  xmax = bars[2,2], ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
                  fill = "pink", alpha = 0.01) +
        geom_rect(aes(xmin = bars[3,1],
                  xmax = bars[3,2], ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
                  fill = "pink", alpha = 0.01))
```

This gives me this desired image:
[image: Desired Image]

I tried using the loop below but it only plots the last bar. How do I do this??

```
## This didn't work but illustrates what I am trying to do
p =  autoplot.zoo(x.zoo, facets = NULL)
for(i in 1:3) {
  p = p + geom_rect(aes(xmin = bars[i,1],
                    xmax = bars[i,2], ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
                    fill = "pink", alpha = 0.01)

}
print(p)
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Sorry - I misspoke. This incarnation of the loop only plots the last bar and not the first two. It does NOT throw an error

Comment: This isn't related to your problem, but ```as.Date()``` give me an error unless I supply an ```origin = ``` parameter specifying how many days to start counting from.

Comment: @divibisan, OP used the `zoo` package. @Ernie, please include the important packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a loop. `geom_rect` is vectorised

```
autoplot.zoo(x.zoo, facets = NULL) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = start, xmax = end, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), data = bars, fill = "pink", alpha = 0.4, inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to avoid the for loop is to convert `x.zoo` into a `data.frame` and map the data to `geom_line`. This way, you can map the `bars` data to `geom_rect` separately.

```
dat <- data.frame(index = index(x.zoo), data.frame(x.zoo))

ggplot() + 
  geom_rect(data = bars, aes(xmin = start, xmax = end, ymin =-Inf, ymax = Inf), fill = 'pink', alpha = .5) +
  geom_line(data=dat, aes(x = index, y = x.zoo))
```